# unable to set sign on url and app Id url

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created an app using apps.dev.microsoft.com . This app shows up in my Azure AD but when I am trying to set the value of the sign on url and the app id url from manage.windowsazure.com and clicking on the save button the save fails with error message:

> This request has a value that is not valid.

I am putting "http://localhost/crm" as the value for APP ID URI and "http://localhost/crm" as value for SIGN-ON URL. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Azure AD v2.0 apps are managed separately from Azure portals. If you also want to manage these apps through Azure portal, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Based on the description, it seems that you want to protect the web API using the Azure AD V2.0 app. To achieve the goal we can acquire the token using the **application Id** instead of **app id Uri**.

And here are two code sample for call the web API which protect by Azure AD V2.0 app from native app and web app.

[Add sign-in to a Windows Desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-wpf)

[Calling a web API from a .NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-webapp-webapi-dotnet)

Comment: To add to what Fei said, if you register an app at apps.dev.microsoft.com it is a v2 app (v2 apps use the converged endpoint allowing auth w/ MSA or Azure AD accounts).  Apps registered at the windowsazure link are traditional Azure AD apps.

Comment: @Fei Xue - MSFT . I am able to obtain the token using the app id and password that are generated from apps.dev.microsoft.com. Only thing I can't do is set this app as a multi-tenant.

Comment: There is no need to enable the app for multi-tenant. The apps you register from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ support multi-tent by default. If you still have the problem and since this is a different issue, to help others understand the issue correctly, I suggest that you reopen a new thread. Please let me know if it helps.